# Integrating ReactJS SPA with Django

Tags: django, reactjs, single-page-application

I have a Django backend working and also a react SPA.

I made the React build to store in Django static files directory, the web page works correctly.

But my problem is Django still handles the routing for e.g the 404 pages and when a user reloads a route page it takes them to Django pages.

Answer (score 0):

Django allows you to override the views responsible for rendering error messages. See [Error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#error-views) and [Customizing error views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) in the docs for details. You can override them to instead serve your react SPA and handle routing and rendering of the error pages there:

E.g. in your URLconf add this line to override which view will render if a `Http404` Error is raised:

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_react_spa_view'
```

Comment: How do I override all routes to render one view which is the React SPA

Comment: @Starbody Could you add your url config to your question? A route is basically a regexp that maches the requested route. So if you have a SPA should only have a single route that matches all subroutes.

Comment: I meant i want the Django route to override all request to a single view

Comment: @Starbody That is what I already said. Create a single url that matches every route and let it point to your only view.

Answer (score 0):

does your url config look like this?

```
url(r'^', views.Index.as_view())
```

Comment: I am using Django 2 and the URL is like `path('', views.index)`

Comment: @Starbody then change it so it looks like mine